# Better way to stop at an exact point?

Tags: java, 2d, game-physics

I'm working on a game that leverages sprites in two dimensional space and I'm trying to figure out a better way to stop at an exact point.

I've gotten the following to work:

```
public void target(boolean hasTargetIn, Point target) {

    if (hasTarget) {
        deltaX = target.getX() - this.mPos.getX();
        deltaY = target.getY() - this.mPos.getY();
        mDirection = Math.atan2(deltaY,deltaX);

        mVelocityX = Math.cos(mDirection) * mSpeed;
        mVelocityY = Math.sin(mDirection) * mSpeed;
    }
    hasTarget = hasTargetIn;

}

public void move(Point target) {

    if (mPos.getX() != target.getX() + 3 && mPos.getY() != target.getY() + 3) {

        this.mPos.x += mVelocityX;
        this.mPos.y += mVelocityY;
    }
}
```

Here are the arguments I'm giving to the method:

```
 sprite.target(true, new Point(700,305));
 sprite.move(new Point(700,305));
```

But this requires me to offset the target.getX() by 3 in the move() method as the X values vacillate between 703 and 697 when the sprite reaches the position (thus it simply stays there jittering without the logic I've included in the move() method). Is there a better way to move and stop at an exact point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the distance to the target. If the distance is greater than the speed just move as normal, if the distance is less than the speed then just move the distance.

You don't need to use `atan2`, `sin` and `cos` to get the normalized deltaX,Y you can just divide the deltas by the distance. Does the same as get direction and using sin and cos.

```
    deltaX = target.getX() - this.mPos.getX();
    deltaY = target.getY() - this.mPos.getY();
    // get the distance
    mDist = Math.sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY);
    if(mDist > 0){
        if(mDist < mSpeed){
            mVelocityX = deltaX;
            mVelocityY = deltaY;
        }else{
            mVelocityX = (deltaX / mDist) * mSpeed;
            mVelocityY = (deltaY / mDist) * mSpeed;
        }
   }else{
        mVelocityX = 0;
        mVelocityY = 0; 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You save the direction. Couldn't you simply stop moving after the direction shifts by about (!) 180 degrees?

On the other hand it could happen that your velocity could be too fast (in other cases), so you wouldn't go over 3 but maybe 300 pixel, so when you recognized (with the direction) that you ran past the target, you turn back with smaller velocity and stop (as I noted before) when you passed the target again with a low velocity.